# Split multidimensional arrays into multiple single arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to split the below array into 3 single arrays. However, the size of the array can be any number. The below array size is 3.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => a 
        [1] => bb 
        [2] => c
        [3] => dd 
        [4] => ee
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => dd 
        [1] => ff 
        [2] => hh 
        [3] => iji 
        [4] => kkk 
        [5] => a 
        [6] => cc 
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => ee 
        [1] => kk 
        [2] => iji 
        [3] => a 
        [4] => bb 
        [5] => lmn 
        [6] => ppq 
        [7] => xyz 
    ) 
)
```

Expected output:

```
Array1 ( 
    [0] => a 
    [1] => bb 
    [2] => c
    [3] => dd 
    [4] => ee
) 

Array2 ( 
    [0] => dd 
    [1] => ff 
    [2] => hh 
    [3] => iji 
    [4] => kkk 
    [5] => a 
    [6] => cc 
)

Array3 ( 
    [0] => ee 
    [1] => kk 
    [2] => iji 
    [3] => a 
    [4] => bb 
    [5] => lmn 
    [6] => ppq 
    [7] => xyz 
)
```

The name of the individual array should be followed by a number that increments for each array.

Comment: the array you posted is already 3 arrays. can you clarify the question..

Comment: in fact you just posted the same array twice

Comment: Expected output is 3 separate arrays having sizes 5, 7 and 8 respectively. The input is a single mutlidimensional array having size 3.

Comment: Why would you want that? That result is harder to use than the original nested array.

Comment: I want to compare values between each of the single array and another array

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it is perfectly clear what is being asked. The code just wasn't formatted properly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you looking for something like this?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputArray); $i++) {
     echo "Array ". $i;
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($inputArray[$i]);
     echo "</pre>";
}
```

Edit: ok now I get it, you want:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputArray); $i++) {
     $name = "array" . ($i + 1);
     $$name = $inputArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: Yes but it should be saved in that variable name like $array1, $array2 etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can break a 3d array into 3 separate arrays using `list()`.

```
list($array1, $array2, $array3) = $mainArray;
```

Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/hQ1Te

---

Now if you don't know how many arrays are going to be in the input array you can do something like this...

```
for($i=0; $i<count($mainArray); $i++){
    $variableName = "array$i";
    $$variableName = $mainArray[$i];
}
var_dump($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, ...);
```

Comment: Why would you tell anyone about `$$variableName`?? Please let it remain an undiscovered secret. It's horrible practice.

Comment: this question is horrible practice. any answer that actually answers the question is going to be horrible practice, idc i just tryna get sme pointss

Comment: @Pamblam here are some points for the use of `$$`. Now if you'll excuse me I've got some variables to rename.